# How can I calculate the time difference in hours, minutes and seconds in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis

```sql
WITH Ride_duration_in_secs AS(
  SELECT ride_id,
         rideable_type,
         CAST(started_at AS DATETIME) AS start_time,
         CAST(ended_at AS DATETIME) AS end_time,
         DATE_DIFF(ended_at,started_at,second) AS Ride_duration,
         FROM `mydataset-342911.Bike_share_tripdata.April_2022_Trip_data`),
Duration_differences AS (
  SELECT ride_id,
         rideable_type,
         start_time,
         end_time,
         Ride_duration,
         Ride_duration_in_secs.Ride_duration % 60 AS seconds_part,
         Ride_duration_in_secs.Ride_duration % 3600 AS minutes_part,
         Ride_duration_in_secs.Ride_duration % (3600/24) AS hours_part
         FROM Ride_duration_in_secs
)
SELECT ride_id,
       rideable_type,
       Duration_differences.start_time,
       Duration_differences.end_time,
       CONCAT(
         FLOOR(seconds_part/3600/24),'days',
         FLOOR(hours_part/60),'hours',
         FLOOR(minutes_part/60),'seconds')
         AS Ride_duration
         FROM Duration_differences;
```

I used the above code to calculate the time diff but it only works on T-SQL not BigQuery, How do I change it to one that executes on Bigquery